# CSS: make div width proportional to height

Tags: html, css, scale

This is a little tricky to explain, but: I want a responsive-height div (`height: 100%`) that will scale the **width** proportional to the **height** (not vice versa).

I know of [this method](https://wellcaffeinated.net/articles/2012/12/10/very-simple-css-only-proportional-resizing-of-elements/) utilising a `padding-top` hack to make the height proportional to the width, but I need it to work the other way around. Having said that, I'm not hugely keen on the additional requirement of absolutely-positioned elements for the content in that method, so I realise I may well be asking for the moon on a stick here.

To help visualise, here is an image:

[image: Visual representation of desired effect]

...and here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V2dyZ/), illustrating pretty much the same thing.

It is worth noting that I am already using the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to vertically-align the content of the box I want to scale proportionally.

I would really enjoy not having to revert to jQuery, just because there's going to be an inherent requirement for resize handlers and generally more debugging all round... but if that's my only choice, then *fiat*.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use javascript for that...

Comment: There is no other way than the trick using `padding` or `margin` http://jsfiddle.net/V2dyZ/3/ . Somehow we have to find some relation between the width and the height so that we can set the height accordingly, however normally the `width` is relative only to the parent's `width`, the `height` is relative only to the parent's `height`, there is only 1 special thing about the `margin` and `padding` that their value in **percentage** (relative value) is based on the parent's `width` no matter you set `padding-top`, `padding-bottom` or `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, so we have a solution (only?)

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/grid-of-responsive-squares/29670456#29670456)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've been wondering about a pure-css solution to this problem for a while. I finally came up with a solution using ems, which can be progressively enhanced using vws:

See codepen link for full working demo and explanation:

http://codepen.io/patrickkunka/pen/yxugb

Simplified version:

```
.parent {
  font-size: 250px; // height of container
  height: 1em;
}

.child {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1em; // 100% of height
}
```

Comment: Using `font-size` here really seems like an ugly and potentially inconvenient hack.

Comment: Super-late accept! I'd totally forgotten I asked this question, then I was googling the exact same thing and my question was first. As it turns out, this did exactly what I was after (with a tiny bit of tweaking for inline proportions - calculated from image size ratios). Thanks for the tip!

Comment: what about the cases we can't have a fixed height ... :(

Comment: You would need to know the height. It doesn't need to be set in px however, you could use any sizing unit (`rem`, `vh`, `vw`, etc).

If the height changes depending on viewport size, you could also change the `height` value via breakpoints.

Answer (score 16):

Oh,you could probably use that "padding-top" trick.

```
width: 50%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 50%;
```

http://absolide.tumblr.com/post/7317210512/full-css-fluid-squares

Or:

```
.square-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
}
.square-box:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

http://codeitdown.com/css-square-rectangle/

The vertical padding in CSS is related to the width of the element, not the height.

Comment: The first is not really applicable because the `div` may contain some content, unless we tweak it a little more with absolute positioning..., of course it's OK if we just need an empty square div.

Comment: Yep, I know about that one; unfortunately the specification of this design is that the width must be set proportionally relative to the height, not the other way around. It looks like I may well be turning to jQuery for this.

Answer (score 7):

The font solution requires that the height is known. I have found a solution for making an element proportional inside a parent div with unknown widths and heights. [Here is a demo](http://divvil.com/proportionalDiv).

The trick I'm using is to have an image used as a spacer. The code explained:

```
<div class="heightLimit">
 <img width="2048" height="2048" class="spacer"
  src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAA
       P///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">
 <div class="filler">
  <div class="proportional">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So it is not the prettiest with two extra divs and a useless image. But it could be worse. The image element needs to have width and height with the desired dimensions. Width and height need to be as large as the maximum size allowed (a feature!).

The css:

```
.heightLimit {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

This element is to limit the height, but to expand horizontally (`width: auto`) although never beyond the parent (`max-width`). Overflow needs to be hidden because some children will protrude outside the div.

```
.spacer {
 width: auto;
 max-height: 100%;
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

This image is invisible and scaled proportionally to the height, while the width is adjusted and forces the width of the parent to also be adjusted.

```
.filler {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

This element is required to fill the space with an absolutely positioned container.

```
.proportional {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0;
 padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

And here our proportional element gets a height proportional to the width with the familiar padding-bottom trick.

Unfortunately, there is a bug in Chrome and IE so if you modify the parent element using Javascript, such as in my demo, the dimensions will not be updated. There is a hack that can be applied to solve that, as shown in my demo.

Comment: What is the significance of `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAA
       P///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7`? Could a regular url be used instead? Specifically I don't get what all the meaningless random-looking characters are for.

Answer (score 4):

You can use view height (vh) as the unity for the **width**.

Here is an example with the 20px margin you asked for.

```
 .parent {
   margin : 20px;
}
.child {
   width: calc(100vh - 40px);
   height : calc(100vh - 40px);
   margin:0 auto;
   background: red;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   padding:10px;
}
```

See the fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/svobczp4/

Answer (score 2):

Based off of @kunkalabs's answer (which is really smart) I've come up with a solution that lets you preserve the inherited font-size.

HTML:

```
<div id='rect'>
    <div id='content'>Text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#rect {
    font-size: 1000%;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    position: relative;
}

#content {
    font-size: 10%;
}
```

So basically the font-size of `#content` is (100 / $rectFontSize) * 100 percent of the rectangle. If you need a definite pixel size for the rectangle, you can set the `#rect`'s parent's font-size…otherwise just adjust the font-size until it's about where you want it to be (and enrage your designer in the process).

Comment: Is there a way to make this scale responsively to the viewport width?

Comment: Good question, there sure is (although you lose the inherited font-width), just change "#rect font-width to use the viewport relative CSS units for the font-size. So something like `font-size: 10vw` means your rectangle will always be 10% of the viewports width and height in the above case. 

If you wanted the content's font to scale to (which isn't a bad idea) leave it as a percent, otherwise you'll have to set a pixel value.

Comment: Think you mean "change `#rect`'s font-*size*", but otherwise, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using SVG.

It depends on a case, but in some it is really usefull. As an example - you can set `background-image` without setting fixed height or use it to embed `<iframe>` with ratio `16:9` and `position:absolute`.

For `3:2` ratio set `viewBox="0 0 3 2"` and so on.

Example:

```css
div{width:35%;background-color:red}
svg{width:100%;display:block;visibility:hidden}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 3 2"></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On newer browsers, we can use `aspect-ratio` with a fixed height, and the width will be calculated accordingly.

```
img {
    aspect-ratio: 1.2;
    height: 250px;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

But the browser support for `aspect-ratio` is not good enough. I liked the `SVG` solution proposed by @Jakub Muda, except for the fact that it requires modifying the markup. I have moved the `SVG` to CSS by including it using `content` property. On newer browsers, it disables the SVG hack and switches to `aspect-ratio` property.

```js
document.querySelector('.nav').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var index = parseInt(e.target.dataset.index);
  if (!index) {
    return;
  }

  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
  for (var i = elements.length; i > 0; i--) {
    elements[i - 1].classList.toggle('hide', i !== index);
  }

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
}

.box {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* SVG Hack */

.box::before {
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  content: 'test';
}

[data-aspect-ratio="1"]::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1 1' height='250'></svg>");
}

[data-aspect-ratio="2"]::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 2 1' height='250'></svg>");
}

[data-aspect-ratio="3"]::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 3 1' height='250'></svg>");
}

@supports (aspect-ratio: 1) {
  /* Modern browsers */
  .box {
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
  }
  .box::before {
    display: none;
  }
  [data-aspect-ratio="1"] {
    aspect-ratio: 1;
  }
  [data-aspect-ratio="2"] {
    aspect-ratio: 2;
  }
  [data-aspect-ratio="3"] {
    aspect-ratio: 2;
  }
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content>svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.nav {
  text-align: center;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Width proportional to height in CSS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box" data-aspect-ratio="1">
      <div class="content">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect x="2" y="2" width="96" height="96" style="fill:#DEDEDE;stroke:#555555;stroke-width:2"/><text x="50%" y="50%" font-size="18" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" font-family="monospace, sans-serif" fill="#555555">100&#215;100</text></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box hide" data-aspect-ratio="2">
      <div class="content">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" width="200" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect x="2" y="2" width="196" height="96" style="fill:#DEDEDE;stroke:#555555;stroke-width:2"/><text x="50%" y="50%" font-size="18" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" font-family="monospace, sans-serif" fill="#555555">200&#215;100</text></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box hide" data-aspect-ratio="3">
      <div class="content">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 300 100" width="300" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect x="2" y="2" width="296" height="96" style="fill:#DEDEDE;stroke:#555555;stroke-width:2"/><text x="50%" y="50%" font-size="18" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" font-family="monospace, sans-serif" fill="#555555">300&#215;100</text></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav">
    <button data-index="1">1</button>
    <button data-index="2">2</button>
    <button data-index="3">3</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Make the parent DIV behave like a table cell and align the child element vertically. No need to do any padding tricks.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
<img src="foo.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent { width:300px; height:300px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; }
```

Comment: The vertically centred content was not the issue - it was making the containing element's height *proportionally responsive* to its width. In your example you use hard-coded values for both.