# Div spacing offset using calc()

Tags: html, css, css-calc

I have 3 vertical rows which are divided on my screen using **calc()**
I'm using JS to set the height for each box type

```
width: calc(1/3 * 100%);
```

This is the javascript to set the height of each block, It's setting the height equal to the width
and in the case of a long box it's setting the height to half the width.

```
$('.box1').height( $('.box1').width() );
$('.box2').height( $('.box2').width() / 2 );
$('.box4').height( $('.box4').width() );
```

I have a weird offset between the columns in the row ( see screenshot )

**You can view the page here http://cloudlabme.webhosting.be/4sr**
[image]

This is the HTML of the two vertical rows

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box box4 box-event" style="background-image: url(build/img/events/2.jpg)"><h1>II</h1></div>
        <div class="box box2 box-medium"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="box box2 box-light"></div>
        <div class="box box1 box-dark"><h3>Hier</h3></div>
        <div class="box box1 box-medium"></div>
        <div class="box box2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: $breakpoint;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 0;
}

.row {
    float: left;
    width: calc(1/3 * 100%);
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

/* BOX */
.box {
    &.box-light {background: #fff;}
    &.box-medium {background: #666;}
    &.box-dark {background: #111;}
}

.box1 {
    float: left;
    width:50%;
    background: #ff4444;
}

.box2 {
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ff6666;
}

.box4 {
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ff8888;
}
```

Thanks! This is killing my brain!

Comment: I could use some CSS with that. Not only HMTL

Comment: 33.33% is being rounded off!

Comment: That might be true! So that's why the big block is higher then the one on the left? any idea what a possible solution might be?

Comment: Use `Math.round($('.box1').width())` and see if the result is satisfying with `int` values for height. Although there are css techniques for that kind of problem but they do have some flaws , too it depends. search for square with css or something

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, the one pixel gap is caused by rounding off error. The only solution I could think of is to force the container width to be a multiple of 3 using JavaScript.

A better solution is to use CSS table display. Set 33.33333333% width on the first two "cells" and let the third one autosize itself. The heights will still be off by one or two pixel but this is better than using `calc()` and fighting with rounding issues.

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
  $('.box1').height($('.box1').width());
  $('.box2').height($('.box2').width() / 2);
  $('.box4').height($('.box4').width());
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #CCC;
}
.row:first-child, .row:first-child + .row {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.box1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: #C99;
}
.box2 {
  clear: left;
  background: #C66;
}
.box4 {
  clear: left;
  background: #C33;
}
h1, h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box box4">
      <h1>II</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box box2"></div>
    <div class="box box1">
      <h3>Hier</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box box2"></div>
    <div class="box box4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really clever! I just have a 1pixel problem now! Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/58l7f8 Thank you!

Comment: I will try your second solution, Any knowsn codepens or tutorials on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: I created a mockup by editing CSS using chrome devtools. Unfortunately, I cannot get _grab_ the edited CSS. I'll try to add a snippet to answer.

Comment: See revised answer. Note that you can ditch JavaScript and set 50% height using "css padding top hack" (google).

Comment: Thank you very much! Taking a look at it now, So with that hack i can ditch all the js for setting the height?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to add one extra inside each box (the technique requires absolute+relative positioning) (http://stackoverflow.com/q/22673008/87015).

Comment: Thanks again! The results are still a bit off? I can't seem to find what the issue is. http://cloudlabme.webhosting.be/4sr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65380/discussion-between-salman-a-and-notflip).