# set proportional to different property ex, width:10%height

Tags: html, css

does it work in `CSS` to set a property by proportion to another property ?
i know that i can do this with `java-script`, but i would be nice if this is possible with `CSS`.

for example : `width:10 % height;`

if not is there any other good way to do it.
thanks for you help.

Comment: You can't do this in CSS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: make div width proportional to height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673008/css-make-div-width-proportional-to-height)

Comment: You can set width to 10% of window height like this `width: calc(100vh*0.1);` with css

Comment: (On a side note, CSS and JavaScript are names, not pieces of code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Nenad's comment I built a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bv5fLrth/20/

Re-size it vertically to see the width change size.

```
#someDiv {
  width: calc(100vh*0.1);
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```